# Display embedded summary in crosstab line header

Tags: crystal-reports, crosstab

I would like to display the same content as an embedded summary in a line header of a crosstab.

[image]

I am able use the distinct count of a field inside the crosstab, but I want to display this value in the line header - such as:

- Line 1 ("distinct count of 1")
- Line 2 ("distinct count of 2")

I tried to modify the formula of the group option, but I can not use Count or DistinctCount inside it. How can I achieve this?

Comment: I think you'll need to add a details section, hide it, but then having a running formula to do the countif on each line of data... the value of this after all data will then be what you want in the header. I don't think you can move a summary from a cross tab directly to the header as it won't know the context...

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. Can you post an example of formula please. I tried to do a sub group with the same criteria as the line group, but I don't know  how to count values in the detail section and how what formula use in the crosstab. Thanks

Comment: You can stand on the LineHeader of the crosstab, right click then choose formatField. Then in the Common Tab click on the (x-2) button near the Display String (almost last line below). Write this formula in it: ToText(DistinctCount (@access...),0,'') But Im not sure about your data and structure to give you a final answer.

Comment: Following your idea, I was able to modify the displayed text. But the DistinctCount does not count the number of distinct `@accessionID` from each Line. I found a solution but I am not totally satisfied: 1- Add embedded summary DistinctCount. 2- I Mark it as deleted (Content is not displayed but an empty cell remains). 3- Put the formula in the Common->Display String option of the line header : `Cstr(GridValueAt (CurrentRowIndex, CurrentColumnIndex +1, 3))`. Any idea to avoid the embedded summary use ?

Comment: There should be no need to group. Just add a details section, put the relevant fields in there (@access would be most important) then add a formula in the group header or footer to do a distinct count. This can then also be put in the page header. Or are you asking for it in the cross-tab column header?